# Issue with dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a issue with dropdown. I have one option in my Dropdown which is called "Add New" so when select "Add new" one form is open,in this form there are few fields and save button.

so when I'm going to save that form,the data should save in database and Key Id Should appear in dropdown.

The issue is,after select Add New,form can open,data can save in DB but the value of Key id is appearing in dropdown only after I refresh the page.
So I want to appear it when I save that form,I should be redirect in the main page..there is no need to refresh the page,directly key id should appear in dropdown..

**here is my code**

```
echo form_dropdown('Key_ID['.$key.']', $optionkey,"",array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'Key_ID['.$key.']','onchange'=>'addKeypeople(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)'));
```

**here is the function**

```
function addKeypeople(){

    if($("#form_keypeoplenew").validate()) {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/KeyPeople/KeyPeoplenew',
                data: $('#form_keypeoplenew').serialize(),
                success:function(result){
                  if(result >0){
                    $('#KeyPeopleModal').hide();
                        var id=result;
                         $('.KeypeopleId').append($('<option>', {
                            value: id,
                            text: $('#KeypeopleKey_ID').val()
                            }
                        ));
                        jsoptkeypeople += '<option value="'+id+'">'+$('#KeypeopleKey_ID').val()+'</option>';
                        //alert (jsoptkeypeople);
                  }
                }
        });
    }
return false;
```

**jsoptkeypeople come from here**

```
$optkey="";
foreach($optionkey as $key=>$value){

    $optkey .="<option value=".$key.">".$value."</option>";
    //print_r ($optionkey);exit;
}
var jsoptkeypeople ='<?php echo $optkey;?>';
```

when i alert **jsoptkeypeople**, then i can see the key id's value but it will not appear in dropdown,key id is appear in dropdown after i refresh the page.

Any Help Please?

Comment: I don't understand your code in `jsoptkeypeople come from here` You use foreach in php ? ok, but why just after you use `var jsopkeypeaple` . It's not correct. Use `$jsoptkeypeople = `. EDIT : and after, use something like `echo json_encode($jsoptkeypeople );`

Comment: we can't write $jsopkeypeaple in javascript..it is javascript code (var jsoptkeypeople ='<?php echo $optkey;?>';)

Comment: So, in javascript you can't use foreach like this. Or please show your full code :)

Comment: <?php
$optkey="";
foreach($optionkey as $key=>$value){
$optkey .="<option value=".$key.">".$value."</option>";
//print_r ($optionkey);exit;
?>
<script>
var jsoptkeypeople ='<?php echo $optkey;?>';
</script>

Comment: you are appending `<option>` in class name with `.KeypeopleId` but in your dropdown there is no class `.KeypeopleId` mentioned

Comment: @Vinie :- thnx a lot ! its works now ! :)